# File ended while scanning use of \\definition

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, amsthm

LaTeX noob here. Basically I get the following message in sharetex:

```
 main.tex: File ended while scanning use of \\definition.
<inserted text> \par <*> main.tex I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me to read past where you wanted me to stop. I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious, you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file. ! Emergency stop. <*> main.tex *** (job aborted, no legal \end found).
```

I think I have pinpointed the region where I get the error message, as when I put `\end{document}` before this region it compiles but when I put it after it doesn't. Please could you see if there's any mistake?

```
\begin{definition}{1.08}
Suppose $f : X\longrightarrow Y$ is a function, and $A\subseteqX$, $B\subseteqY$.
\\*\item[(i)] We define the image set of f, denoted im(f), by im(f)=$\{f(x) \vert x\inX\}$.
\item[(ii)] We define the image set of A under f, denoted f(A), by f(A)=$\{f(x) \vert x\in A\}$.
\item[(iii)] We define the inverse image set of B under f, denoted $f^{-1}(B)$, by $f^{-1}(B)=\{x\inX \vert f(x)\in B\}$.
\end{definition}.
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error you're getting would appear to be the `\\*` snippet; I can't tell what it's for. LaTeX will also choke on `\inX`, `\subseteqX`, and `\subseteqY`; there needs to a be a gap between the control sequence and the subsequent material. The use of `\item` statements while not in a `list` environment (such as `itemize` or `enumerate`) is also going to throw an error.

I would strongly recommend using `\mid` rather than `\vert` when expressing thoughts such as "conditional on", "given that", and "subject to". The macro `\mid` adds some horizontal spacing around the vertical bar, whereas `\vert` does not. Knuth, by the way, also recommends inserting `\,` (a "thin space") after the opening left curly brace and before the closing right curly brace in the conditioning statement.

Since you posted a code snippet rather than an entire MWE (minimum working example), I had to make a guess as to how the `definition` environment is defined.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition} % adjust this setup to your needs
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newcommand{\image}{\mathit{im}} % better to define a macro to define the appearance of "image"
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{definition}[1.08]
Suppose $f : X\longrightarrow Y$ is a function, and $A\subseteq X$, $B\subseteq Y$.
\begin{itemize}
\item[(i)] We define the image set of $f$, denoted $\image(f)$, by $\image(f)=\{\,f(x) \mid  x\in X\,\}$.
\item[(ii)] We define the image set of $A$ under $f$, denoted $f(A)$, by $f(A)=\{\,f(x) \mid  x\in A\,\}$.
\item[(iii)] We define the inverse image set of $B$ under $f$, denoted $f^{-1}(B)$, by $f^{-1}(B)=\{\,x\in X \mid  f(x)\in B\,\}$.
\end{itemize}
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd rather make my own macro instead of the `\mid`, could be as simple as `\let\given\mid` then the code makes much more sense $\{ x \in A \given x^2 \in A \}$

Comment: @daleif - Point taken. The main issue I meant to raise was that `\vert` is definitely not correct in this context.

Comment: of course, I tend to define macros for things like `\{ ... \given ... \}` via `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` such that `\given get its height via the scaling choice in the macro. I think this is a better approach because users tend to get confused when they discover that `\mid` does not scale.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my problem was sorted and you also answered another question of mines before I even asked it. Thanks again, friend.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet says nothing about used packages, hence `definition` is commented. This is only a suggestion, but the general type of errors is: omitting space between macro name and next `X` or `Y`. Please observe also that `f` and `$f$` are different objects. Probably also `im` should be as `\sin`, i.e. upright, with some spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

%\begin{definition}{1.08} 
Suppose $f : X\longrightarrow Y$ is a function, and 
$A\subseteq X$, $B\subseteq Y$. 
\begin{itemize}
\item[(i)] We define the image set of $ f$, denoted $im(f)$, by $ im(f)={f(x) \vert x\in X}$. 
\item[(ii)] We define the image set of $A$ under$ f$, denoted $f(A)$, by$ f(A)={f(x) \vert x\in A}$. 
\item[(iii)] We define the inverse image set of  $B$ under $f$, denoted $f^{-1}(B)$, by $f^{-1}(B)={x\in X \vert f(x)\in B}$. 
\end{itemize}

%\end{definition}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not promote users to use `\item[(i)]` to number their lists.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who may be reading this: it may be just that you need to blow away the `.aux` etc temporary files and re-build. I just found it out a hard way, when the MiKTeX servers were very slow to respond and a package install pop-up did not show up until minutes later while I was pulling my hair trying to find why a perfectly good file, which compiles fine on a co-worker's machine suddenly stopped compiling on mine. And when I was in the middle of trying to run an update, the download dialog popped up.

Then after everything was updated and seemed to be fine, PDFLatex kept throwing the same error `the file ended scanning for the definition of LT@i` until I blew away all temporary files and voila, it compiled.